# How to extract any subset of digits from a numeric column

Tags: python, numpy

I have an integer column(int64) in a dataframe with values as 20170811. (yyyymmdd)
Now i need to extract 08 only and store it as a new column.

```
df['key'].floordiv(10000)
```

gives me 2017. But i wanted 08 - how to get it ?

Comment: It might be better to treat that value as a string rather than integer.

Answer (score 0):

**New Answer** (as requested in comments)

Converting to `Datetime` has several advantages if you want to format your datetime string. In order to do so you can use [`DataFrame.dt.strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html). For more information on how to format strings and create custmo formats take a look at [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['20181201', '20180302', '20180403']})

pd.to_datetime(df.key).dt.strftime('%b')
```

This will output:

```
0    Dec
1    Mar
2    Apr
Name: key, dtype: object
```

---

**Old Answer**

What you can do is take the module of the value, divide it by 100 and drop the decimals:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['20181201', '20180302', '20180403']}).astype(int)

df['key'].map(lambda x: int((x % 10000) / 100))
```

Which outputs:

```
0    12
1     3
2     4
Name: key, dtype: int64
```

In case you have strings, you could convert it to `Datetime` objects and simply access `month`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['20181201', '20180302', '20180403']})

pd.to_datetime(df.key).map(lambda x: x.month)
```

giving you the same output.

---

Comment: Thanks Stefan, just wanted to add bit more now. Instead of giving the output as 12, 3, 4. Is it possible to display the month ? Like Dec, Mar, Apr ?

Comment: @Sheriff Yes ofc. I've updated my answer and references some links you might want to checkout.

Answer (score 0):

Or use:

```
df['key']=df.astype(str)['key'].map(lambda x: x[4:6]).astype(int)
```

As you said to @Stefan, do:

```
import calendar
df['key']=df.astype(str)['key'].map(lambda x: x[4:6]).astype(int).apply(lambda x: calendar.month_name[int(x)-1])
```

Or `apply`:

```
df['key']=df.astype(str)['key'].apply(lambda x: x[4:6]).astype(int)
```

As you said to @Stefan, do:

```
import calendar
df['key']=df.astype(str)['key'].apply(lambda x: x[4:6]).astype(int).apply(lambda x: calendar.month_name[int(x)-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the most robust way is:

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': [20180201, 20180302, 20180403]})
df['month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'].astype(str), format='%Y%m%d').map(lambda x: x.strftime('%m'))
```

If you wanted the `df['month']` to be integer, just cast it with `col.astype(int)`.

Edit:
If you wanted your month in a format of Apr, May, etc., use `x.strftime('%b')`. You may want to look at [strftime documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your series to a string and then slice using Pandas `str` methods:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': [20180201, 20180302, 20180403]})

df['key'] = df['date'].astype(str).str[4:6]

print(df)

       date key
0  20180201  02
1  20180302  03
2  20180403  04
```

A much better alternative is to convert to `datetime` and extract months as integers:

```
df['key'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'].astype(str)).dt.month

print(df)

       date  key
0  20180201    2
1  20180302    3
2  20180403    4
```